# The greatest value of the speed after a collision

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

Three particles P, Q and R of masses $0.1$ , $0.2$ and $0.5$ respectively lie on a smooth horizontal table , P is projected towards Q with speed $5$ ,after the collision P rebounds with speed $1$ , then Q collides with R , after the collision R moves with speed $v$ .

Given that there is no subsequent collision between P and Q , find the greatest value of $v$

My turn

For the collision between P and Q

$0.1 \times 5 + 0 = 0.1\times -1 + 0.2 v_{Q}$

$v_{Q} = 3$

For the collision between Q and R

$3 \times 0.2 + 0 = 0.2 \times v_{1} + 0.5 \times v$

Since there is no subsequent collision between P and Q , then $v_{1}$ (the speed of Q after is collides R) $-1\geq v_{1} $

Then we get

$v \geq 1.6$ which means the least value of v is 1.6 not the greatest

What is the mistake ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe you should use energy-conservation in addition to momentum.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Arithmetic dynamics. Please, choose your tags carefully. You should read the tags description if you don't know what they are.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the condition for no further collision is $$v_1\geq-1$$, so your inequality is reversed and you will arrive at the correct answer.

If you're still not sure about this, consider what would happen if, as you said, $v_1$ takes a value less than $-1$ such as $-2$...?

Comment: For no subsequent collision the speed of Q after the collision with R must be less than the speed of P , but the speed of P is 1 in the opposite direction , so the speed of Q must be less than 1 in the same direction of P so the velocity must be less than -1 , is not it ? @David Quinn

Comment: You seem to be confusing speed with velocity. The conservation of momentum equation involves velocities. If the initial velocity of $P$ is $5$ with left to right as positive, the rebound velocity is $-1$ and the velocity of $Q$ is $+3$ (going from left to right). For the collision between $Q$ and $R$ you are getting an equation linking the **velocities** of $Q$ and $R$ after impact. The velocity of $R$ must be positive anyway and to avoid collision with $P$ the velocity of $Q$ must take any value greater than or equal to that of $P$, i.e. $\geq$-1$

Comment: This is correct. To piggyback off of this answer, $3$×$0.2+0=0.2$×$v_1+0.5$×$v$ and 0≥$v_1$≥-1. So, the limits of $v$ are $1.2$≥$v$≥$0.8$